# Link momentarily blue on first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I'm having this weird problem in Chrome where a link flashes blue for a second before becoming the desired black.

This only happens on the first page load and not if you refresh the page.

See for yourself: http://www.jacobklassdesign.com

If I clear the browser data, I get this moment of blue again on the first page load!

I have included all of the anchor tag CSS:

```
a {color:#000}
a:link {color:#000}
a:visited {color:#000}
a:hover {color:#000}
a:active {color:#000}
```

There is a script below that causes the link to fade to white once the scroll meets the anchor, I think this may be involved, but not sure how.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(function () {
        var a = function () {
            var b = $(window).scrollTop();
            var d = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top;
            var c = $("#title");

            if (b > d) {
                c.css({ color: "white" })
            } else {
                if (b <= d) {
                    c.css({ color: "black" })
                }
            }
        };
        $(window).scroll(a);
        a()
    });
});
```

Comment: What links exactly are you talking about? All the links I see on the page are white, not black.

Comment: not a single link is showing up as blue :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the delay the browser has downloading the `css` file and and applying it to the document.

In case this is extremely important for you it is possible to embed the style inline or on page

Answer (score 0):

Looks for me like a problem with the transition all on a tag. Change it to color.